# A pilot faces a medium-term loss of their medical. What can they expect?

Tags: pilots, medical, career

[This closely related question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/13613/167) asks about what options a pilot has when facing a *permanent* loss of medical.

However, not all disqualifying conditions are permanent. Maybe you got an interesting disease known for its 7-month contagious period. Maybe you broke an important, slow healing bone. At any rate, whatever silly thing you did to yourself, you *will* be flying again, but it will take several months.

**As a pilot, what options do you have during this period of your career?**  Are you likely to be furloughed?  Assigned alternate duties? I'm interested in answers relating primarily to the United States or Europe.

Comment: Really need to clarify the question.  From the context, it seems that you mean just commercial pilots, who are a small subset of all pilots. That question might be better answered on e.g. the Workplace or Legal sites, since it has more to do with legal treatment of disabilities than flying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will first and foremost depend on the carrier you are working for and if they have anything in place for such a case. There are personal insurance policies out there to cover this exact case, [like this one](https://www.piu.org/personal-disability-insurance/pilot-license-medical) and [this one](https://www.insubuy.com/pilot-disability-insurance/). Some carriers may offer policies like this in house for their employees as well.

If available to you it might be possible to [spend some time in the sim](https://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=822531) without a medical or (if you are allowed to) instruct and work with other pilots at the company for ground based instruction.